# TYPO3 faceted search (ke_search) basic setup

Tags: typo3, typoscript, faceted-search, typo3-7.6.x

I am trying to set up the Faceted search (ke_search) in TYPO3 7.6.4.

I followed all the steps of the [quick installation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/ke_search/ExtFacetedSearch/QuickInstallation/%28%28generated%29%29/Index.html) in the documentation but then doing a test search doesn't seem to do anything.

I am inexperienced in this area so it's possible I have missed some obvious part that the documentation didn't feel the need to state... or is there some trick to get this working?

Comment: Do you understand German? There is a very good documentation: https://www.typo3-macher.de/facettierte-suche-ke-search/dokumentation/einleitung/. Have you started the indexing process? I recommend editing the extension settings (within the extension manager) and set up an email notification for the indexing process. After running the indexer, you'll get an email. We have to make sure, your pages are indexed. You could also check your database if it gets field up with entries.

Comment: Don't know German unfortunately. I am working on an installation that holds many sites, and there was one other site that was already using the search setup in the past - so the indexer was already started. I used "removelock" and then started the index again, now I am getting something. Do I need to do that every time pages are added?

Comment: I now realise there is a English option on the site you linked, very helpful! One last question: The search results are always the same listing of indexed items. Does this mean I am missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Perfect. I do not understand your last question. Did you set up multiple indexers? Let's say you want to index tt_content, tt_news or news, cal and an own extension, you need to create 4 indexing configuration. For every extension/ table you need an own indexer. If you created your own extension (let's say for seminars) then you have to program your own indexer.

Comment: I have set it to index pages. No matter what I type in the search field, the results page is exactly the same. It always shows all the indexed pages in the same order...